# how I can map enum in CreateIndexDescriptor method that from Nest library-ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I create my map service for City entity. City entity is like this;

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string LocalName { get; set; }
public int Population { get; set; }
public RegionType RegionType { get; set; }
```

And my CreateIndexDescriptor method is like this;

```
public static CreateIndexDescriptor CityMapping(this CreateIndexDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return descriptor.Map<City>(m => m.Properties(p => p
            .Keyword(k => k.Name(n => n.Id))
            .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Name))
            .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.RegionType))
            .Number(t => t.Name(n => n.Population))
            .Date(t => t.Name(n => n.CreateDate)))
        );
```

RegionType is an enum. Did I apply to mapping as correct ?

Comment: I am not sure you are stating the issue you are facing. Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to know mapping of enum properties

Comment: Well, without further info. My 2 cents would be to map an enum to a field with type keyword.